# openssl_private_decrypt does not return anything PHP

Tags: php, android, encryption, openssl, rsa

**Updates:**

`openssl_error_string()` gives:

```
error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02 
error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed
```

I generate a pair of public key and private key using OpenSSL on my server:

```
$config = array(
        "private_key_bits" => 2048,
        "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    );

    $res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
```

I sent the Base64-encode modulus and exponent to my Android client. My Android client reconstruct the public key from the modulus and exponent received. My Android client then encrypt a message using such key. Lastly, my Android client sends back to the server the encrypted message expecting the server to be able to decrypt it.

I have a simple PHP script on my server to test the decryption of the encrypted message from my Android client:

```
$sms_message = $argv[1];
$sender_no = $argv[2];

echo "Message received was: '$sms_message' \n";
echo "sender's no was: $sender_no \n";

$parts = array();
$parts = explode(" ", $sms_message);
if (count($parts)==2) {
    echo "code: $parts[0] \n";
    if (strcmp($parts[0], "smscode")==0) {
        echo "measurement: $parts[1] \n";
        // retrieve the private key
        $keyArr = array();
        $keyArr = getKeys();
        //
        if ($keyArr) {
            $privateKey = $keyArr["private"];
            echo "$privateKey \n";
            // use the private key to decrypt the message
            echo openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($parts[1]), $decrypted, $privateKey); // this is supposed to return either TRUE or FALSE right?

            echo $decrypted;

            $decryptedMessages = "decrypted.txt";

            if (!$fh = fopen($decryptedMessages, 'a')) {
                echo "cannot open file $decryptedMessages";
                exit;
            }   

            // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
            if (fwrite($fh, $decrypted) === FALSE) {
                              echo "Cannot write to file ($decryptedMessages)";
                                          exit;
            }                 
            //                            
            fclose($fh);
        }   
    } else {
        echo "what received is not a measurement - $parts[1] \n";
    } 
} else {
    echo "sms message malformed";
}
```

I ran the following:

```
php SmsReceiver.php 'smscode adDmHJDFmI8bC9KRcA7nPbTc2NU0sY7iM5jDHt3qJVq/AAyl9thUB3zVH5/9Jr+pTM4V+dift6UD8uB3nEU53thrY7nx55PsackCYzmBoKYTE4tazsyF7tRfAIawxvmR4lcSfKL2+A0N9ZetISoqqZAHI141n47Wtd52n0pE9tdLRGzXQlfeDOC3ntnbOKcIIhbyJWekLg+58uCLm2nfWPA4EveAd7t6RQPX4E20wXXQ1RgkVPCQsW+9WDdrbxav6y0VN7uKoBqA4/G8zn3Ol41OPtFFllBgl1BGUFWK3xcxxxZqodTCc3pTdAIHgJ4td+pktUjfbAwITt/RMC+IcA==' +6511111111
Message received was: 'smscode adDmHJDFmI8bC9KRcA7nPbTc2NU0sY7iM5jDHt3qJVq/AAyl9thUB3zVH5/9Jr+pTM4V+dift6UD8uB3nEU53thrY7nx55PsackCYzmBoKYTE4tazsyF7tRfAIawxvmR4lcSfKL2+A0N9ZetISoqqZAHI141n47Wtd52n0pE9tdLRGzXQlfeDOC3ntnbOKcIIhbyJWekLg+58uCLm2nfWPA4EveAd7t6RQPX4E20wXXQ1RgkVPCQsW+9WDdrbxav6y0VN7uKoBqA4/G8zn3Ol41OPtFFllBgl1BGUFWK3xcxxxZqodTCc3pTdAIHgJ4td+pktUjfbAwITt/RMC+IcA==' 
sender's no was: +6511111111 
code: smscode 
measurement: adDmHJDFmI8bC9KRcA7nPbTc2NU0sY7iM5jDHt3qJVq/AAyl9thUB3zVH5/9Jr+pTM4V+dift6UD8uB3nEU53thrY7nx55PsackCYzmBoKYTE4tazsyF7tRfAIawxvmR4lcSfKL2+A0N9ZetISoqqZAHI141n47Wtd52n0pE9tdLRGzXQlfeDOC3ntnbOKcIIhbyJWekLg+58uCLm2nfWPA4EveAd7t6RQPX4E20wXXQ1RgkVPCQsW+9WDdrbxav6y0VN7uKoBqA4/G8zn3Ol41OPtFFllBgl1BGUFWK3xcxxxZqodTCc3pTdAIHgJ4td+pktUjfbAwITt/RMC+IcA== 
private key found 
public key found 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQC7dArHUiEXpEwi
...
F/EaVVWEZLevTJEdMpkfvQVr/08AlSLR3Nm33CrvQ1SfFygK0F6G6o1pQtnHlCKh
DK8/dT2CgsFuDbiAs4MRqQA36g==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

As you can see, `openssl_private_decrypt()` does not return anything, why?
Even if something is wrong with my encrypting/ decrypting process, at least give a `false` I'd expect.

Based64-encoded modulus of the public key:

```
u3QKx1IhF6RMIvncMADBhGqhdlSWnuuUz0dXr9NUzXJtgfPgvX/07w1IKTls6uj48eZ4J3s5me4xUzoRwIsxjk6Ondke2vGVJgzBZh3KQSml0dQoK/0a3Bc/bHwue3jroCCAaC/4lF6GQS5gB1gDQntkKBM+RaHaEqGldKHmF1T8Sg1zSLAU9IGBc+xDSCqgo2RepntB0npctBGmAYF8gdzN1PnAwgVfOLU/xi08ssQL1ppkrMncgPegaOOkyUZm4BXSyEY9ikYynLfoiQqEAFb9mU40yNM7LQusgqF0YhUgUIg+4fuQNscZJCJ6pS9UTQ64MHWCqrpXCeRAZ4rWeQ==
```

Based64-encoded exponent of the public key:

```
AQAB
```

Private key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Android logcat:

```
I/SmsReceiver(15814): message received is keyx u3QKx1IhF6RMIvncMADBhGqhdlSWnuuUz0dXr9NUzXJtgfPgvX/07w1IKTls6uj48eZ4J3s5me4xUzoRwIsxjk6Ondke2vGVJgzBZh3KQSml0dQoK/0a3Bc/bHwue3jroCCAaC/4lF6GQS5gB1gDQntkKBM+RaHaEqGldKHmF1T8Sg1zSLAU9IGBc+xDSCqgo2RepntB0npctBGmAYF8gdzN1PnAwgVfOLU/xi08ssQL1ppkrMncgPegaOOkyUZm4BXSyEY9ikYynLfoiQqEAFb9mU40yNM7LQusgqF0YhUgUIg+4fuQNscZJCJ6pS9UTQ64MHWCqrpXCeRAZ4rWeQ== AQAB
I/SmsReceiver(15814): message received is a key exchange message
I/SmsReceiver(15814): the recipient's public key modulus is 23663785522794809498963221782819553495813344590754203802091214078741934630870755737273483338578650343553350487999568641527155675069988138202941338180146715141856273325699348180697949807604837968252319802254132361756796150729526732643616381939360742823851037800072915016799286519177887771453765989612342846498554824903381084855033387403868553674907286294016751397407403976788809972626838594376008433688839811350345997686592001128890405964489889151586297624459113817319199310865303723716614014342885058854916172119790960266134365108047747227357851477353947042531226823494283658181608350838513970607286067323054395676281 and exponent is 65537
I/SmsReceiver(15814): successfully remembered the contact +6500000000 and its public key module u3QKx1IhF6RMIvncMADBhGqhdlSWnuuUz0dXr9NUzXJtgfPgvX/07w1IKTls6uj48eZ4J3s5me4xUzoRwIsxjk6Ondke2vGVJgzBZh3KQSml0dQoK/0a3Bc/bHwue3jroCCAaC/4lF6GQS5gB1gDQntkKBM+RaHaEqGldKHmF1T8Sg1zSLAU9IGBc+xDSCqgo2RepntB0npctBGmAYF8gdzN1PnAwgVfOLU/xi08ssQL1ppkrMncgPegaOOkyUZm4BXSyEY9ikYynLfoiQqEAFb9mU40yNM7LQusgqF0YhUgUIg+4fuQNscZJCJ6pS9UTQ64MHWCqrpXCeRAZ4rWeQ== and exponent AQAB
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL asymmetric cryptography is not suitable for encrypting large files unless you use S/MIME. In fact, this is what I tried:

1. Decoded the base64-encoded 'measurement:' field. The decoded message was 256 bytes in length.
2. Tried to decrypt this 256 bytes with the private key that you pasted using the following openssl command:

`openssl rsautl -decrypt -in x.in -out plaintext -inkey private.key`

But, I got an error instead:

`RSA operation error`

`139982152128160:error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02:rsa_pk1.c:190:`

`139982152128160:error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:rsa_eay.c:616:`

In fact, I tried this using PHP itself. But, instead of doing an `echo` of `$decrypted`, I used `openssl_error_string` and it gave me the exact above error.

Also, I wasn't able to encrypt a 256 byte data with public key as well. I got error from openssl indicating `139870762710688:error:0406D06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_type_2:data too large for key size:rsa_pk1.c:151:`.

All of this seems to indicate that OpenSSL's asymmetric cryptography is not meant for encrypting large data (in this case, 256 bytes is large enough). I am not sure how the Android client was able to encrypt it. Did it use OpenSSL as well?

However, there are relevant posts on how to deal with this. Take a look at:

1. [how to encrypt a large file in openssl using public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143514/how-to-encrypt-a-large-file-in-openssl-using-public-key)
2. Encrypt with S/MIME: http://ashmek.weebly.com/1/post/2011/02/encrypt-large-files-with-a-public-key-via-openssl.html

Comment: A limit of RSA is that you cannot encrypt data longer than the key size. If you need to encrypt large amounts of data with RSA, you should encrypt the actual data with AES (or other symmetric cipher) and then encrypt the AES key with RSA.