# How to use encrypted files of one account in the another account

Tags: c++, windows, security

I have a C++ program which uses some configuration files. The configuration files should not be available for end-user, so I created an administrative account on windows and encrypt config files using `properties -> General -> Advanced -> Encrypt contents to secure data`. In the other account, when I want to use the program, I should run it as different user and enter username and password of the privileged account. Need to enter password every time is not convenient and I want to omit this step.
What should I do if I want to access configuration files via my C++ program without needing to enter password every time, but do not let an end-user access the files?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by having a server X509 certificate that you encrypt the configuration files and a shared private key that you give to all account that are allowed to decrypt the files.

Have a look at [@JakubBoucek answer for how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143514/how-to-encrypt-a-large-file-in-openssl-using-public-key) , it was not the accepted answer but is still a valid solution for the problem at hand.